# Is there a downside of always using fragile?

Tags: beamer, listings, environments, verbatim, fragile

I am preparing a presentation and since I am presenting a lot of code, I find myself adding `[fragile]` to many slides such that I can put `verbatim` code in it (actually `lstlisting` from from the `listings` package).

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
\begin{lstlisting}
double arr[5][12][27];
\end{lstlisting}
Blah
\end{frame}
```

It is so common that now I am putting `fragile` just-in-case and to avoid a surprising compilation error.

What is the cost or downside of adding `fragile` to all the slides?

If there is none, why packages such as Beamer just don't set the environments to be fragile by default?

Comment: +1 for a serious question. No, I can't answer it, but it is generally not too useful an attitude to upvote someone only to increase the probability to get the tick... ;-)

Comment: Iirc, it has a performance impact, because the whole frame is temporarily saved to disk…